# Why do I receive an RDD error when I convert JSON on Athena Spark notebook?

Tags: pyspark, amazon-athena

I'm trying to fetch json from a REST API and than convert it inside a spark DF, so I'm doing like that :

```
df = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize([my_json]))
df.show(truncate=False)
```

I receive an Error :

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 501, in parallelize
    raise Exception('Athena does not support RDD')
Exception: Athena does not support RDD
```

Thanks in advance

UPDATE :
[image]

Comment: can you share your imports

Comment: @eemrah I've updated my post with the previous code